# SharePoint REST API - Return current user list item permission level with item data

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, javascript, rest, sharepoint-rest-api

With an items query like this:
`_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Docs')/items`

Is it possible to also include what permission level the current user has on a given item?

My list items have unique permissions, and a user may have read or edit permissions on the data returned. I'm wondering if there is a way via a single REST query to include that information along with the list item data.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `RoleAssignments` of list items using single REST endpoint in below format:

```
<siteUrl>/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('List Name')/items?$select=Title,RoleAssignments&$expand=RoleAssignments
```

This will give you user `PrincipalId` which you can match with current user ID in client side code (JavaScript).

```
<d:PrincipalId m:type="Edm.Int32">4</d:PrincipalId>
```

Comment: I'm looking for the permission level - whether they have read or write access. I didn't see that in the returned data with RoleAssignments.

Comment: I don't think you can get all permission details in one call. You can get the permissions for specific `PrincipalId` using endpoint like: `.../Items(1)/RoleAssignments/GetByPrincipalId(3)/RoleDefinitionBindings`